# Python OpenCV with multiple webcams - Please tell me how to tell which webcams

Tags: opencv

I'm attempting a multiple camera setup with OpenCV in the windows10.

I want to use the camera in a fixed location. In order to do that, it is necessary to distinguish the camera.

I'm not sure how to match the OpenCV `VideoCapture` ID to a certain camera.

I tried the following code

```
from pygrabber.dshow_graph import FilterGraph

def get_available_cameras() :

    devices = FilterGraph().get_input_devices()
    aa = FilterGraph()
    print(devices)
    print(aa)
    available_cameras = {}

    for device_index, device_name in enumerate(devices):
        available_cameras[device_index] = device_name

    return available_cameras

print(get_available_cameras())
```

Result

```
{0: 'C922 Pro Stream Webcam', 1: 'USB Video Device'}
```

That's ok

but

```
{0: 'C922 Pro Stream Webcam', 1: 'C922 Pro Stream Webcam', 2: 'C922 Pro Stream Webcam'}
```

That's not ok

If the camera name is different, I can somehow solve it, but if the camera name is the same, I have a problem.

I want the following result

```
{0: ['C922 Pro Stream Webcam', unique identification number], 1: ['C922 Pro Stream Webcam', unique identification number], 2: ['C922 Pro Stream Webcam', unique identification number]}
```

How can I match opencv VideoCapture ID and Webcam

Comment: OpenCV can't do this. Its API is simple. you need to use whatever media apis your operating system provides. then you have a chance of telling these cameras apart by UID.